# Drawing solid triange in a cube result in flicker

Tags: c++, algorithm, graphics, vector-graphics

I'm trying to draw a cube using software rendering. So I have I'm drawing a cube out of triangles. So I render a solid triangle. The cube is rendered successfully, but there are flicker while rotating it.

here is my solid triangle filling, can somebody notice a problem in the algorithm?

```
void Rasterizer::DrawSolidTriangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color&color)
{
    // Sort our points into order of y
    // 0 top
    // 2 middle
    // 1 bottom
    if (y1 < y0)
    {
        swap(y1, y0);
        swap(x1, x0);
    }
    if (y2 < y0)
    {
        swap(y2, y0);
        swap(x2, x0);
    }
    if (y1 < y2)
    {
        swap(y2, y1);
        swap(x2, x1);
    }

    float xl_edge = (float)x0;  // left edge
    float xr_edge = (float)x0;  // right edge

    float dxldy;
    float dxrdy;

    float dxdy1 = (float)(x2 - x0) / (y2 - y0);
    float dxdy2 = (float)(x1 - x0) / (y1 - y0);

    if (dxdy1 < dxdy2)
    {
        dxldy = dxdy1;
        dxrdy = dxdy2;
    }
    else
    {
        dxldy = dxdy2;
        dxrdy = dxdy1;
    }


    // Top of the triangle
    for (int y = y0; y<y2; y++)
    {

        for (int x = xl_edge; x<xr_edge; x++)
        {
            SetPixel((unsigned int)x, (unsigned int)y, color);

        }//end for loop x

        xl_edge = xl_edge + dxldy;
        xr_edge = xr_edge + dxrdy;

    }// end for loop y


    // Bottom half of the triangle

    if (dxdy1 < dxdy2)
    {
        dxldy = (float)(x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1);
    }
    else
    {
        dxrdy = (float)(x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1);
    }


    for (int y = y2; y<y1; y++)
    {

        for (int x = xl_edge; x<xr_edge; x++)
        {
            SetPixel((unsigned int)x, (unsigned int)y, color);
        }//end for loop x

        xl_edge = xl_edge + dxldy;
        xr_edge = xr_edge + dxrdy;

    }// end for loop y

}
```

here is a screenshot of the problem, when rotating the cube so slow it does appear here:

[image]

Comment: 1. Make sure you are drawing "back to front" so that faces farther from the camera don't draw over nearer faces.  2. If it's possible for your frame buffer to be in a half-complete state when the screen draw happens, consider adding double buffering to prevent the flicker of half-drawn objects.

Comment: The most obvious thing that stands out to _me_ is the fact that you're calling SetPixel in a loop to draw horizontal runs of the same colour. Hmmmmm. Consider simply drawing a horiz line between the two end-points.

Comment: @0x5453 How to ensure number 1) ? I'm just having a constant camera looking at 0,0,0 with angles,0,0,0.

Comment: @0x5453 I'm using SDL Surface, so I'm sure it does double buffering

Comment: @AndreAhmed Unfortunately we've pretty much reached the extent of my graphics knowledge.  :p  I think this is where you want a [Z-buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering).

Comment: @AndreAhmed - you can store the polygons along with their centroids (avg pos of the vertices) after they've been transformed to camera space. You can then sort this list of polygons based on Z value, from largest to smallest. When John Carmack wrote the engine for RAGE, one of his primary aims was to ensure zero-overdraw - why paint a pixel over and over and over again - you'll only see the last colour painted, ZBuffering is one way of achieving this, it wasn't his primary tool though from memory. It makes for an interesting read. The engine used is known as `id Tech 5`.

Comment: The cyan triangle seems wrong for cube, also if by flicker you mean that whole triangles are missing during some rotations I can think of these reasons: wrong face culling (if wrong normal computation), something fishy in the triangle rasterizer try to add draw triangle border lines at start of triangle rasterizer so when you take the screenshot and triangle is missing but  the border lines not that mean your rasterizer is not rendering such triangle (may be missed delta sign combination or underflow or whatever) so you should detect which triangle it is and debug it ...

Comment: To be sure for triangle `A,B,C` and point `D=(A+B+C)/3` draw lines `AB,BC,CD,AD,BD,CD` so you can safely decide which lines belongs to which triangle